# c++ variant No such file or directory

Tags: c++, g++, variant

I have a problem compiling code using std::variant. 
I try to compile this code with g++ 5.4/6.2 on ubuntu and fedora with -std=c++17:

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::variant<int, float> v, w;
    v = 12; // v contains int
    int i = std::get<int>(v);
    w = std::get<int>(v);
    w = std::get<0>(v); // same effect as the previous line
    w = v; // same effect as the previous line

    try {
      std::get<float>(w); // w contains int, not float: will throw
    }
    catch (std::bad_variant_access&) {}

    std::variant<std::string> v("abc"); // converting constructors work when unambiguous
    v = "def"; // converting assignment also works when unambiguous
}
```

found on cppreference.com but this error append: "fatal error: variant: No such file or directory".

Comment: Please include the invocation of the compiler complete with all flags. `std::variant` is a C++17 feature. Did you specify `-std=c++17`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::variant` was added in C++17.

gcc does not yet fully support the relevant bits of the C++17 standard.

I don't even see `std::variant` listed in the [gcc's tracking page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx1z).

Comment: Looks like it will at least compile with a [gcc 7 snapshot](https://godbolt.org/g/jirajD)

Answer (score 7):

1. Install g++-7;  e.g. if ubuntu
   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test -y
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install g++-7`
2. run `/usr/bin/g++-7 -std=c++1z your_program.cc`
3. Optional, if you use `cmake` system, add these lines :
   `set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER  "/usr/bin/g++-7")
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++1z")`