# c++17 install problems on Linux vm

Tags: c++, linux, travis-ci

I am using Travis CI to deploy a python script that uses z3. When I run it on my (windows) laptop and on a Linux VM from VirtualBox it works. However, with Travis CI I can't get z3 to download properly. I lost track of all the things I have tried..
Right now I have these commands in my .travis.yml file

```
script:
  - git clone https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3.git
  - cd z3
  - python3 scripts/mk_make.py --python
  - cd build
  - make
  - sudo make install
  - cd ..
  - cd fall-2021/project
  - python -m unittest formula_gen_tests.py
```

But it errors on the make command. I don't know what to do.

```
Type 'cd build; make' to build Z3
The command "python3 scripts/mk_make.py --python" exited with 0.
0.00s$ cd build
The command "cd build" exited with 0.
0.37s$ make
src/shell/gparams_register_modules.cpp
In file included from ../src/ast/normal_forms/nnf.h:22:0,
                 from ../src/shell/gparams_register_modules.cpp:5:
../src/ast/ast.h:50:19: fatal error: variant: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:4513: recipe for target 'shell/gparams_register_modules.o' failed
make: *** [shell/gparams_register_modules.o] Error 1
The command "make" exited with 2.
0.16s$ sudo make install
src/shell/gparams_register_modules.cpp
In file included from ../src/ast/normal_forms/nnf.h:22:0,
                 from ../src/shell/gparams_register_modules.cpp:5:
../src/ast/ast.h:50:19: fatal error: variant: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:4513: recipe for target 'shell/gparams_register_modules.o' failed
make: *** [shell/gparams_register_modules.o] Error 1
The command "sudo make install" exited with 2.
```

Previously I tried just having z3, z3-solver, or a combination of both in requirements.txt but they all lead to errors such as "z3 ImportError: cannot import name 'Solver'" etc. So I tried this since this is how I got it to work on my linux vm. Help! Not sure what details are relevant, feel free to ask for more!

Answer (score 0):

`variant` is a C++17 feature. Most likely the compiler on your CI machine doesn't support everything C++17 has. Make sure you get a really recent version of g++ on that machine, if you can.

Here's some further discussion: [c++ variant No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40177006/c-variant-no-such-file-or-directory?rq=1)

Comment: but where do you place the - std=c++17 flag I tried a couple places (in addition to other commands from the link you sent) and I am getting errors such as ```$ g++ -std=c++17 -o testcode1 ../src/shell/gparams_register_modules.cpp
../src/shell/gparams_regis``` I don't understand why this is not included in the Makefile provided by z3. I only have a .travis.yml file

Comment: Make sure your CI g++ is a recent version. What does `g++ --version` produce? Also, better tag this as a C++ question as it really has nothing to do with `z3py`.

Comment: ```$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609``` not sure what that implies, according to google the latest g++ version is 1.42. Also, you're right, I'm very unfamiliar with all this so I didn't realize this wasn't a z3py problem when I asked.

Comment: `20160609` means this `g++` dates back to 2016. Obviously, it won't have C++17 features. It's just too old.

Comment: Unless you're using a very powerful CI system (i.e., custom in-house) I'd strongly advise against trying to compile z3 in a public CI infrastructure. (Like travis, for instance.) The budgets you'll have regarding time/memory/software will just not suffice. Instead, see if you can "download" a prebuilt z3, from here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/releases

Comment: Or, even, unzip one of these releases into your source-tree, then directly use it from there. That would simplify things as you don't even have to figure out how to download a package from the internet on a public CI system. You can then update that bundle periodically.

Comment: Okay I added ```z3_solver-4.8.12.0-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl``` unzipped to the source tree. But what do I have to do after? any commands to make it work? I am getting the same ```fatal error: variant: No such file or directory``` error

Comment: You're not going to build anymore. Get a package that has the binary in it, and just use z3 from there. (i.e., your travis script should *not* attempt any builds at all.)

Comment: This is a silly question but _how_ do I upload one of the releases to the source tree? GitHub says the file is too large, and I tried to do it manually but it kept deleting my work.

Comment: If Github has restrictions on file-size, then you're out-of-luck. I'm assuming you're using a free repo, which probably has these sorts of restrictions. There are ways of downloading files off the internet using Travis, but they are finicky. I recommend you ask a new question with the appropriate travis/CI tags for help from the experts.

Comment: See this line, for instance, on how I used to do this a couple of years ago: https://github.com/LeventErkok/sbv/blob/de9682cd25e3d534eea85a855946b0225ef5a444/.travis.yml#L46, which "downloads" a version of z3 on Travis and unpacks it. But I should warn you that I gave up on this myself; the downloads are finicky, the name of the z3-release changes; it's a pain to automate. But if you really need something like this it can give you a starting point.